# Product images in storefront are missing after migration to Intershop 7.9

Tags: intershop

After migrating to Intershop Commerce Management 7.9 the product images in list and details views are missing. Only "No Image Available" is displayed.

In the back office the images are still assigned correctly and visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason**:
Deprecated methods from bc_image have been removed in release 7.9, see "Guide - 7.9 API Changes"
https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/2X8235

One of the deprecated methods is ImageContainerBO.getImage(), which was still referenced in ISML template app_sf_responsive/staticfiles/cartridge/templates/default/modules/common/Image.isml

```
<isset name="image" value="#imagecontainer:Image(imagetypeid, imageview)#" scope="request">
```

**Fix**: 
Just change Image to ImageBO:

```
<!--- determine image --->
<isif condition="#isDefined(imageview) AND (imageview NE '')#">
    <isset name="image" value="#imagecontainer:ImageBO(imagetypeid, imageview)#" scope="request">
<iselse>
    <isset name="image" value="#imagecontainer:PrimaryImageBO(imagetypeid)#" scope="request">
</isif>
```